# Convert date/time (PHP)

Tags: php

Is there an easy way to convert date and time like this:

```
Sun, 14 Mar 2010 09:00:00 GMT
```

To this format:

```
20100306T153626
```

in PHP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) and [`date`](http://php.net/date) functions.

```
$result = date('Ymd\THis', strtotime('Sun, 14 Mar 2010 09:00:00 GMT'));
```

The “T” has to be escaped, because it has special meaning (timezone abbreviation).

Comment: how can we convert the date into unix time.

Comment: `strtotime` already returns a UNIX timestamp.

Comment: @Matej Grabovsky : I have tried on todays with converstion to unix and human readable date format. here is the link http://codepad.org/jGD0Y3Qe , dont why? i did something wrong. can you help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You want the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.  The format string for 20100306T153626 is:

```
YmdTHis
```

i.e.

```
date("Ymd\THis");
```

for the current date/time.  If you want to use your own time, you'll need it as a Unix timestamp, which you can use the [mktime](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) function for that.