# PHP simple date format

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I have a date that I need to convert using PHP date. I've tried a couple different things with no success.

Date coming in: **2011/10/14**

Date I need going out: **October 2011**

Do I need to convert my incoming date to time, and then from time to date going out? I don't understand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert date/time (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412402/convert-date-time-php) Virtually all questions about converting dates in PHP can be solved by `strtotime()` or `mktime()` or the `DateTime` class. Some more resources: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+convert+date

Comment: No need to convert it to time: http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) and its [format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method:

```
$date = new DateTime('2011/10/14');
echo $date->format('F Y');
```

Answer (score 3):

`date("F Y", strtotime($date));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$date_out = date("F Y", strtotime($date_in));
```

`strtotime` converts a string value to a timestamp.

`date` converts a timestamp into a string representation based on the format provided as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can almost certainly accomplish that and pretty much almost problem related to date/time convertion using the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class of PHP core.